# Facebook OAuth access_token error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Full code.

```
    public function indexAction(){
           echo '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=475302972487577&redirect_uri=http://bp.mysite.com/en/social/fblogin" target="_blank">Login met facebook</a> ';
  }

 const FB_GRAPH_URL =  "https://graph.facebook.com/";  
    public function fbloginAction() {

            $fbCode = $this->_getParam("code");
            $getStr  = self::FB_GRAPH_URL. 'oauth/access_token?' .http_build_query(array(
                        'client_id'     => 'APP_ID',
                        'type'          => 'client_cred',
                        'client_secret' => 'SECRET_KEY',
                        'code'          => $fbCode)
                    );

            $accessToken = file_get_contents( $getStr );
            krumo($accessToken) ;

            $dbpath = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?$accessToken" ;
            $cont = file_get_contents($dbpath ) ;
            krumo($cont);
        }
```

When i try make GET query to Facebook.

```
$dbpath = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?$accessToken" ;
$cont = file_get_contents($dbpath ) ;
```

I receive the  error :

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
>   in /home.....

When paste manually  the $dbpath value(path) to web browser,  i got next error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

How fix that error?

Comment: If you aren't experienced enough to read, understand and implement oauth2, why don't you use [facebook's official php sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)?

Comment: Sir, i can't under stand how to use it. Examples for this SDk's is not worked on my site.  Where i can find "step by step" manual to use Facebook API?

Comment: 1. http://developers.facebook.com/ 2. there are [several examples](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/examples) shipped with fb php sdk

Comment: Using the SDK _really_ makes a lot of things easier to handle; I __strongly__ recommend using it instead of doing things “manually”, which is a lot more error-prone and has many pitfalls that definitively don’t make things easier for a beginner. (If you’re having problems using it, then we could discuss those.) – As for your code, none of us knows what your function `krumo()` is supposed to be doing …

Comment: Thank you sir. I use a Facebook SDK. But i not Understand what a error:  "code": 2500  How to fix that?  Krumo() It very nice debugger for PHP programmers. You can find it on next link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/krumo/files/

Comment: Yes, i have a problems with using SDK. I think, my be i have error in my Application settings on FB.com side. It possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the Server-Side Authentication flow. By checking the calls in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) it is quite clear, which of your calls are wrong.

First, your call to the `oauth/access_token` endpoint takes no argument `'type' => 'client_cred'`, but it needs the parameter for your `redirect_uri` again:

```
$getStr = self::FB_GRAPH_URL . 'oauth/access_token?' . http_build_query(array(
           'client_id'     => 'APP_ID',
           'redirect_uri'  => 'REDIRECT_URI',
           'client_secret' => 'SECRET_KEY',
           'code'          => $fbCode)
          );
```

Then, you can't just take the answer of this call as your `access_token`, as there is much more in it:

```
access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN&expires=NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_UNTIL_TOKEN_EXPIRES
```

and you only want the `access_token` part of it:

```
$response = file_get_contents($getStr);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);

$dbpath = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $params['access_token'];
```